# AWS DMS doesn't properly load text columns from Postgres on-prem to Aurora Serverless

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, database-migration, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I am facing with an issue where I have a bunch of columns which are `text` as datatype in my on-prem database instance.

When I run DMS using a `dms.t3.micro` instance, the text columns are not properly transferred. I took into consideration all the needed settings for the on-prem but I am wondering why this is not working.

The maximum size for a specific value varies from 10 - 15kb.
In the logs I don't find anything suspicious:

```
2023-04-07T06:57:08:287106 [TARGET_LOAD ]T: Insert row to table 'table_1' with LOB Lookup ('3' LOBs) (odbc_util.c:3874)
```

When using validation, I get `Mismatched records` on this tables as they are not transfered.

Spotted this in the logs after the full load completed:

```
2023-04-07T07:23:30:466649 [VALIDATOR       ]D:  iSourceLatency : 0, iTargetLatency : 1226882  iMigrationLatency : 2453764  (replicationtask.c:3626)
```

Can anyone give a proper explanation please?

Here are my DMS settings:

```
    {
    "Logging": {
        "EnableLogging": true,
        "EnableLogContext": false,
        "LogComponents": [
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TRANSFORMATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_UNLOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "IO"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
                "Id": "TARGET_LOAD"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "PERFORMANCE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SOURCE_CAPTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "SORTER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "REST_SERVER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DETAILED_DEBUG",
                "Id": "VALIDATOR_EXT"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TARGET_APPLY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TASK_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "TABLES_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "METADATA_MANAGER"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_FACTORY"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMON"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "ADDONS"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "DATA_STRUCTURE"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "COMMUNICATION"
            },
            {
                "Severity": "LOGGER_SEVERITY_DEFAULT",
                "Id": "FILE_TRANSFER"
            }
        ]
    },
    "StreamBufferSettings": {
        "StreamBufferCount": 3,
        "StreamBufferSizeInMB": 8,
        "CtrlStreamBufferSizeInMB": 5
    },
    "ErrorBehavior": {
        "FailOnNoTablesCaptured": true,
        "ApplyErrorUpdatePolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "FailOnTransactionConsistencyBreached": false,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottlingMax": 1800,
        "DataErrorEscalationPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "RecoverableErrorStopRetryAfterThrottlingMax": true,
        "RecoverableErrorThrottling": true,
        "ApplyErrorFailOnTruncationDdl": false,
        "DataTruncationErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "ApplyErrorInsertPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "EventErrorPolicy": "IGNORE",
        "ApplyErrorEscalationPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "RecoverableErrorCount": -1,
        "DataErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "TableErrorEscalationPolicy": "STOP_TASK",
        "RecoverableErrorInterval": 5,
        "ApplyErrorDeletePolicy": "IGNORE_RECORD",
        "TableErrorEscalationCount": 0,
        "FullLoadIgnoreConflicts": true,
        "DataErrorPolicy": "LOG_ERROR",
        "TableErrorPolicy": "SUSPEND_TABLE"
    },
    "ValidationSettings": {
        "EnableValidation": false
    },
    "TTSettings": null,
    "FullLoadSettings": {
        "CreatePkAfterFullLoad": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesApplied": false,
        "StopTaskCachedChangesNotApplied": false,
        "MaxFullLoadSubTasks": 2,
        "TransactionConsistencyTimeout": 600,
        "CommitRate": 100,
        "TargetTablePrepMode": "DROP_AND_CREATE"
    },
    "TargetMetadata": {
        "TargetSchema": "",
        "SupportLobs": true,
        "FullLobMode": true,
        "LobChunkSize": 64,
        "LimitedSizeLobMode": false,
        "InlineLobMaxSize": 4,
        "LoadMaxFileSize": 0,
        "BatchApplyEnabled": false,
        "ParallelLoadThreads": 0,
        "ParallelLoadBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelLoadQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "ParallelApplyThreads": 0,
        "ParallelApplyBufferSize": 0,
        "ParallelApplyQueuesPerThread": 0,
        "TaskRecoveryTableEnabled": false
    },
    "ControlTablesSettings": {
        "historyTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTimeslotInMinutes": 5,
        "HistoryTableEnabled": true,
        "SuspendedTablesTableEnabled": true,
        "StatusTableEnabled": true,
        "FullLoadExceptionTableEnabled": false
    },
    "ChangeProcessingTuning": {
        "BatchApplyPreserveTransaction": true,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMin": 1,
        "BatchApplyTimeoutMax": 30,
        "BatchApplyMemoryLimit": 500,
        "BatchSplitSize": 0,
        "MinTransactionSize": 1000,
        "CommitTimeout": 1,
        "MemoryLimitTotal": 1024,
        "MemoryKeepTime": 60,
        "StatementCacheSize": 50
    },
    "ChangeProcessingDdlHandlingPolicy": {
        "HandleSourceTableDropped": true,
        "HandleSourceTableTruncated": true,
        "HandleSourceTableAltered": true
    },
    "PostProcessingRules": null,
    "BeforeImageSettings": null,
    "LoopbackPreventionSettings": null,
    "CharacterSetSettings": null,
    "FailTaskWhenCleanTaskResourceFailed": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've had the same issue trying to transform PSQL/TEXT fields, leading to silent failures (empty data on target).

AWS support pointed out the docs that confirm, at the time of writing, the only supported transformation for columns that are mapped to [BLOB/CLOB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.PostgreSQL.html) data types is to drop the column on the target. Assume `BLOB/CLOB/NCLOB`.

See, [dms docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.html#CHAP_Tasks.CustomizingTasks.TableMapping.SelectionTransformation.Transformations.Limitations)